# How to update 'null' data with Joi at Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, joi

I am using Joi module and mongoose at Nodejs.
And I made updatedata code using Joi.
Joi condition doesn't have 'required()' here.
When it is patched by postman like 'abcd', it added well.
But I want to put '' as null data also.
 In this case, error is occured , even though Joi doesnt' have required().
Could you recommend some solution?

```
const clientMemoValidate = Joi.object().keys({
  memo: Joi.string().max(10),
});
```

This 
is mongoose code.

```
await Client.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: req.body.id },
            { memo: req.body.memo },
            {
              upsert: true,
              new: true,
            },
          );
```

Comment: Just for clarification. When the client sends null data for ```req.body.memo``` you want to know how to store this in the database? Is the ```memo``` field on the Client schema required?

Comment: Yes. I want that. And In Client schema , memo doesn't have required..

Comment: Did you try using .allow(null)?